# Cars with no ACC power

Tags: electrical, gm

I have a car that wouldn't turn on the cigar power supply when the key is on the ACC position. It comes on when I put it in the IGN, so I'm pretty sure this is by design. This is a horrible design for me because I often use the car battery to charge my phone or just sit in the car to chill and listen to the stereo. Also, the fuses are not labelled(just amps) so I wouldn't be able to figure out which fuse to take out when some electronics go cranky.

The question is: are all GM cars designed like this?

Comment: I've had bad experiences with the strict rules of Stack Exchange, so before anyone flagging this question, I wanna acknowledge that I'm not asking for a solution to a specific problem. If this post doesn't fit here, just take it down.

Comment: And please no "just buy japanese cars!"

Comment: Most cars I've seen work that way @DavidA, I can't think of any that work on accessory mode. I don't know why.

Comment: Closed as opinion based? Really, If you want I can get the wiring diagram for my car and it will show 1 controlled by ignition and one fed direct from the battery.

Comment: @SolarMike I know how to read diagrams, too. The problem is that I don't want to spend money to buy the workshop manual.

Comment: How strange. All the cars I've owned and driven worked "the other way". I don't see the point of having ACC if I can't use the simple accessory like the cigar lighter. Might as well just have OFF and IGN like forklifts.

Comment: I just realised that someone edited my question. Wow. I'll just go somewhere else to get opinions. You guys are not doing well as a community. Where's my free speech?

Comment: @DavidA - I'm sorry for your displeasure, however, if you understand how SE works, it's not about opinions, it's about objectivity and what can be proven. Most of the stacks in SE/SO work exactly that way. Your question was edited to allow it to be re-opened. If that doesn't sit well with you, I'll go ahead and close the question again as it's border line even after it was edited. This is not a regular forum and free speech is not a given. Fact and being kind to one another is, which is what was in mind when the question was modified.

Answer (score 1):

Some cars have multiple cigar lighter sockets and then:

1. some will be battery direct,
2. some acc controlled, and
3. some ign controlled.

It just depends on how they decide to do it and what current limits they wish to implement, some will be 5A others can be more.

My car has one limited to 12A, battery direct in the rear. I use this to easily connect a battery charger in winter.

Comment: The question was that I don't like how they implement and I want to avoid the makes that do this.

Comment: My GM '03 Saturn L300 has front and rear auxiliary power outlets. 'HOT' and protected by separate fuses. I've slow charged a faulty battery using the rear outlet on the back of the center console with a trickle charger, the ac cord out the closed trunk lid. Doors locked, ignition switch OFF, Passlock antitheft system enabled for overnight charging. Finding wiring diagrams may help if you want to bypass existing wiring while retaining fused power to the power outlet. This shouldn't be difficult if you're comfortable with rewiring without creating new issues.